# Error while opening "Graphical Summary" for survey

Tags: 2013, list-view, survey, survey-list

I am getting an error while opening the `Graphical summary` for a survey in SharePoint 2013:

> Error=The specified view is invalid

Below is the ULS log:

> Application error when access /sites/subsite/Lists/surveyList/summary.aspx, Error=The specified view is invalid.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.get_Item(Guid guid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.EnsureListAndView(Boolean requireFullBlownViewSchema)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.IWebPartPageComponentProvider.get_WebPartContextualInfo()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.RegisterRibbonTabs()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the page by opening the overview.aspx page in designer. There I saw link to another survey list. I think that this list was created from the template of that survey list. So I removed the old link and it worked!!

I removed the link from the `<DetailLink></DetailLink>` tag inside the `<WebPart>` tag. Please refer to below screenshot:

[image]